# I want my values in one row in my SQLITE Database to increase by 1 everyday at Midnight or every 24 hrs its in the Database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a Database that has a row that needs to increase by 1 every 24 hours. I enter "19" that first day. Either at midnight or 24 hours Later I would like that value to Change to "20". Is there a way to do that?

Your help would be Appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `trigger` in `SQLite` or you can have `AlarmManager` in `JAVA`.
For `trigger` you can visit [SQLite trigger](http://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html)
For `AlarmManager` you can visit [Alarm Manager Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8801990/2194831)

Answer (score 1):

There are no computed columns in SQLite, and on the Android platform you can't rely on a background process.  But all you have to do is add a date column "created" along with your value.  Each time you query, add the [day difference](http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) between now and "created" to the original column to get the value you need.

```
SELECT [myval] + julianday(Date('now')) - julianday([created])) FROM mytable
```

Comment: Would Insert that command into onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)? If not would section of the database class would insert that command?

Comment: +1 That would also be my approach. Note that you can have computed columns in views!